# av_interleaved_write_frame() unknown error when streaming WebM

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm following [a guide to live WebM streaming through FFMpeg / FFServer](https://www.virag.si/2012/11/streaming-live-webm-video-with-ffmpeg/) and running into an interesting error. I have tried using a DirectShow webcam source, and also an existing WebM (finite length) video using -vcodec copy. Initially, both will manage to connect to the FFServer (I can see the POST 200 OKs to /feed1.ffm), and maybe even send a frame or two, but then FFMpeg crashes with `av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error`. (Meanwhile, FFServer appears to be fine.)

This appears to be an unusual variant of the error - normally it's more common to get, say, `av_interleaved_write_frame(): I/O error` (which indicates file corruption). Has anyone seen this error, and better yet, can anyone tell me how to fix it?

---

### FFMpeg commands

- `ffmpeg -re -i univac.webm -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f webm http://[my server]/feed1.ffm`
- `ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="[my dshow source]" -f webm http://[my server]/feed1.ffm`

### FFserver command

`ffserver -f ffserver.conf`

### ffserver.conf

This is only a slight variation in the one provided in the aforementioned guide.

```
Port 8080  
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 5
# MaxBandwidth 10000 
CustomLog -
NoDaemon  

<Feed feed1.ffm>       
   File ./feed1.ffm   
   FileMaxSize 1G  
   ACL allow [IP of the machine with ffmpeg]  
</Feed>

<Stream test.webm> 
   Feed feed1.ffm    
   Format webm

   # Audio settings
   AudioCodec vorbis
   AudioBitRate 64   

   # Video settings
   VideoCodec libvpx
   VideoSize 640x480
   VideoFrameRate 30
   AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
   AVOptionVideo cpu-used 0
   AVOptionVideo qmin 10
   AVOptionVideo qmax 42
   AVOptionVideo quality good
   AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
   VideoBitRate 400

   # Streaming settings
   PreRoll 15
   StartSendOnKey
</Stream>
```

### FFserver logs

`avserver version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers`

`built on Mar 30 2013 with gcc 4.7.2`

`AVserver started`

`[current time] - [GET] "/feed1.ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 4149`

`[current time] - [POST] "/feed1.ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 4096`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by using different versions of ffmpeg and ffserver.
Try to use the same version. They should work without a problem.
In addition, use only libav or ffmpeg, because they are probably not quite compatible with each other.

Comment: In the end I solved my specific problem with a rather different approach not based on FFMPEG, but I believe the problem did indeed stem from using different versions of ffmpeg and ffserver.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I'm having the same problem and both versions are the exact same.

Answer (score 0):

The connection was establish by tcp and after I get the error on the client 'av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error'. And I get 'Connection timed out' on the server.

For me, I found that I had an other process listened on the same port that ffmpeg was configured to used on the client.

to check used ports command:

(windows) netstat -a -b
  (ubuntu)  netstat -a -p

I used a custom ffmpeg inside a folder. The command used 'ffmpeg' used the wrong ffmpeg. Then I change it to './ffmpeg'.

Comment: Would a process listening on the same port even allow the connection the OP describes and then crash? What sort of error message did you receive when you observed this behavior?  Elaborate more on your answer.